# How to activate site setting option in powershell?

Tags: powershell, page-layout, site-settings

I want to set "**subsites can only use the following site templates**" radio button true in  **settings** > **Page Layout and Site Templates** how to do this process in powershell?

Answer (score 2):

Try this script

```
 $templateNamesToKeep = "STS#0","PROJECTSITE#0","BLOG#0"

 Start-SPAssignment -Global
 $web = Get-SPWeb <URL of site> 

 # get the existing web templates from the site that will be filtered down 
 # 1033 is the locale id for English US (en-us), be sure to change to your locale 
 $existingWebTemplates = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) 
 $newWebTemplates = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplate]"

 # filter existing web templates and only keep if in the list of template names to keep 
 $newWebTemplates = $existingWebTemplates | Where-Object {$_.name -in $templateNamesToKeep} 
 $web.SetAvailableWebTemplates($newWebTemplates, 1033) 
 $web.Update() 

 Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

at `$templateNamesToKeep` define the template that you need to only use for subsites.

For more details check [Set PageLayouts and Site Templates Settings in SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Set-PageLayouts-and-Site-Templates-Settings-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell)

Comment: When I added custom template to the $templateNamesToKeep Its not working. custom site template look like "CustomTemplate#CA18553C-D520-4E1D-8FD4-E57CCF24AA36"

Comment: are you sure it's the custom template it should like  "{YOUR GUID}#TemplateName"

Comment: Oh .. Sorry I Interchanged that thing

Comment: Please try this and tell me the result :)